# Find and replace using functional javascript and ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am looking into ramda and have t questions, from the following [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20original%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20speakers%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Author%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20words%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.360000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27Arthur%27%2C%20time%3A%20%270.660000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.150000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27the%27%2C%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%271.020000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.380000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27rat%27%2C%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%271.170000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.770000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27.%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%271.550000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.360000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27Arthur%27%2C%20time%3A%20%2789.820000%27%2C%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p1-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.390000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27stood%27%2C%20%20time%3A%20%2790.180000%27%2C%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p1-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.090000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27and%27%2C%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%2790.570000%27%2C%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p1-0%27%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20words%20%3D%20R.lensPath%28%5B%27speakers%27%2C%20%27words%27%5D%29%0Aconst%20wordsList%20%3D%20R.view%28words%2C%20original%29%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20%5B...wordsList.reduce%28%28hash%2C%20%7B%20duration%2C%20time%2C%20name%2C%20paragraph%20%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20current%20%3D%20hash.get%28paragraph%29%20%7C%7C%20%7B%20paragraph%2C%20words%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20current.words.push%28%7B%20duration%2C%20time%2C%20name%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20hash.set%28paragraph%2C%20current%29%3B%0A%7D%2C%20new%20Map%29.values%28%29%5D%3B%0A):

```
const R = require('ramda')
//const original = require('./test/fixtures/original.json')
const original = {
  speakers: {
    name: 'Author',
    words: [
      { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', time: '0.660000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.150000', name: 'the',    time: '1.020000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.380000', name: 'rat',    time: '1.170000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.770000', name: '.',      time: '1.550000',   paragraph: 'p0-0' },
      { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', time: '89.820000',  paragraph: 'p1-0' },
      { duration: '0.390000', name: 'stood',  time: '90.180000',  paragraph: 'p1-0' },
      { duration: '0.090000', name: 'and',    time: '90.570000',  paragraph: 'p1-0' }
    ]
  }
}

const words = R.lensPath(['speakers', 'words'])
const wordsList = R.view(words, original)
const result = [...wordsList.reduce((hash, { duration, time, name, paragraph }) => {
  const current = hash.get(paragraph) || { paragraph, words: [] };

  current.words.push({ duration, time, name });

  return hash.set(paragraph, current);
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

How do I use `groupBy` in order to get it grouped by paragraphs instead of the above method?

From this result, how do I do a find of a string that can have one or more items, by sorting all the words in order of time and returning only the matched paragraphs?

```
search_criteria = 'Arthur stood';

results = [ 
  { para: 'p1-0', 
    words: [
      { 'name': 'Arthur', 'time': 89.820000},
      { 'name': 'stood', 'time': 90.180000}
  }
]
```

How would you replace these items with `replace = 'Arthuro stopped'`?

Any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: Question is not clear. You need to ask short and concise questions and create a separate question for each problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your first problem with Ramda would be like this:

```
pipe(
  view(lensPath(['speakers', 'words'])),  // original.speakers.words (null-safe)
  groupBy(prop('paragraph')),             // object with keys of para name, values of list of matching records
  map(map(dissoc('paragraph'))),          // removing unneeded para from records
  toPairs,                                // {p1: [...words1], p2: [...words2]} => [[p1, [...words1]], [p2, [...words2]]] 
  map(zipObj(['paragraph', 'words']))     // expected output structure
)(original)
```

You asked specifically about `groupBy`.  After the `groupBy(prop('paragraph'))` clause, the data looks like this:

```
{
  "p0-0": [
    {duration: "0.360000", name: "Arthur", paragraph: "p0-0", time: "0.660000"},
    {duration: "0.150000", name: "the", paragraph: "p0-0", time: "1.020000"},
    {duration: "0.380000", name: "rat", paragraph: "p0-0", time: "1.170000"},
    {duration: "0.770000", name: ".", paragraph: "p0-0", time: "1.550000"}
  ],
  "p1-0": [
    {duration: "0.360000", name: "Arthur", paragraph: "p1-0", time: "89.820000"},
    {duration: "0.390000", name: "stood", paragraph: "p1-0", time: "90.180000"},
    {duration: "0.090000", name: "and", paragraph: "p1-0", time: "90.570000"}
  ]
}
```

The remainder is just fiddling to get the output structure you're looking for.

You can see the results in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20original%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20speakers%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Author%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20words%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.360000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27Arthur%27%2C%20time%3A%20%270.660000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.150000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27the%27%2C%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%271.020000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.380000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27rat%27%2C%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%271.170000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.770000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27.%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%271.550000%27%2C%20%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p0-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.360000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27Arthur%27%2C%20time%3A%20%2789.820000%27%2C%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p1-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.390000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27stood%27%2C%20%20time%3A%20%2790.180000%27%2C%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p1-0%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.090000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27and%27%2C%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%2790.570000%27%2C%20%20paragraph%3A%20%27p1-0%27%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20]%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apipe%28%0A%20%20view%28lensPath%28[%27speakers%27%2C%20%27words%27]%29%29%2C%20%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%28%27paragraph%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28map%28dissoc%28%27paragraph%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20map%28zipObj%28[%27paragraph%27%2C%20%27words%27]%29%29%0A%29%28original%29)**. (If you comment out later lines in the pipe, you can see any intermediate results.)

For the second half of your question, I'd suggest you open a new topic, demonstrating what you've attempted so far.